# Displaying another app in my form

Tags: c#, .net, c++, forms, integrate

I remember I had some app the launched other applications and placed them in tabs in it's form without the titlebars.
I wonder how can that be done?
Preferably with C# but if it's not possible/too hard within .NET C++ is fine too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications like Excel and Internet Explorer provide specific support (OLE) for being embedded in other windows, so third-party application can run an instance of them within their own window easily.

If the application you wish to embed doesn't supply specific support for it, it would be much harder to achieve. It's easy to control the target application's windows to make them appear to be in your tabs, but when it comes to removing/hiding specific sub-parts of the windows (borders and menus etc) it gets a lot more difficult (all depending on exactly which bits of the application's display you wish to alter).

Comment: Well I already found the andwer by digging in the MSDN documentation..
I will use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633541%28VS.85%29.aspx and other API's to hide titlebars and such.
But thanks for the help anyway :)

Comment: I doubt that the functions you found will do what you want. THe OLE discussion jason was saying is what should the answer. Maybe im wrong, but let us know if setParent() works

Comment: Of course it works - what I wanted was to place an application onto my form, and I can do that within C# by pinvoking setParent() and calling it with the needed parameters.

Comment: As I said, it's easy to force another application's windows to appear in a tab (although some applications may behave unpredictably in this situation, most won't notice), just difficult to remove bits of their windows to customise their appearance more.